# Angular & Jasmine Unit Test change event for input[type="file"]

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to go for 100% test coverage, but i can't seem to test the stuff inside this onUploadFile function.

## html template

```
<input type="file" formControlName="theUpload" id="upload" (change)="onUploadFile($event, i, true)">
```

## filing.ts file

```
onUploadFile(evt: Event, index: number, isReq: boolean = false): void {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  const target = <HTMLInputElement>evt.target;

  if (target.files && target.files.length) {
    const file = target.files[0];
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => {
      this.getUploadFormGroup(index, isReq).patchValue({
        filename: file.name,
        filetype: file.type,
        value: reader.result.split(',')[1],
        dateUploaded: new Date()
      });

      console.log(
        `getUploadFormArray (${isReq ? 'required' : 'other'} forms)`,
        this.getUploadFormArray(isReq)
      );
    };
  }
}
```

## filing.spec.ts file

```
it('should call onUploadFile when input is changed for required files', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'onUploadFile').and.callThrough();

  const fakeChangeEvent = new Event('change');

  const targ = <HTMLInputElement>de.nativeElement.querySelector('input#upload');
  targ.dispatchEvent(fakeChangeEvent);

  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(component.onUploadFile).toHaveBeenCalledWith(fakeChangeEvent, 0, true);
    expect(targ.files.length).toBeGreaterThan(0); //  this is always zero because i can't add to targ.files (readonly FileList)
  });
});
```

I am open to mocking whatever can be mocked, but can someone please show me how I might test the `console.log` function (requiring that i have at least one item in the `target.files` array?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's follow the *divide and conquer* rule - since the aim of Unit Test is to test the parts of component logic separately, I would slightly change the component logic in order to make it easier to Unit Test.

You're setting the anonymous callback function for `onload` inside your `onUploadFile` method, so there is no way to spyOn it. As a trade off - you can refactor out the callback method:

```
export class TestComponent {
  ...
  getLoadCallback(fg: FormGroup, file: File, reader: FileReader): () => void {
    return () => {
      fg.patchValue({
        filename: file.name,
        filetype: file.type,
        value: reader.result.split(',')[1],
        dateUploaded: new Date()
      });

      // do some other stuff here
    };
  }

  onUploadFile(evt: Event, index: number, isReq: boolean = false): void {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const target = <HTMLInputElement>evt.target;

    if (target.files && target.files.length) {
      const file = target.files[0];
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      const fg = this.getUploadFormGroup(index, isReq);
      reader.onload = this.getLoadCallback(fg, file, reader);
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

So, now we can create at least three Unit Tests: one for triggering `onUploadFile` on input event (your existing test is good for this), another one for testing `getLoadCallback` method and lastly - for `onUploadFile` method:

```
  it('getLoadCallback', () => {
    const mockValue = ['a', 'b'];
    const result = jasmine.createSpyObj('result', ['split']);
    result.split.and.callFake(() => mockValue);
    const mockReader = { result } as FileReader;
    const mockFormGroup: FormGroup = jasmine.createSpyObj('FormGroup', ['patchValue']);
    const mockFile = new File([''], 'filename', { type: 'text/html' });
    const callback: () => void = component.getLoadCallback(mockFormGroup, mockFile, mockReader);

    callback();

    const obj = {
      filename: mockFile.name,
      filetype: mockFile.type,
      value: mockValue[1],
      dateUploaded: new Date()
    }
    expect(mockFormGroup.patchValue).toHaveBeenCalledWith(obj);
  });

  it('onUploadFile', () => {
    const mockIndex = 1;
    const mockIsReq = false;
    const mockFile = new File([''], 'filename', { type: 'text/html' });
    const mockFormGroup = new FormGroup({});
    const mockEvt = { target: { files: [mockFile] } };
    const mockReader: FileReader = jasmine.createSpyObj('FileReader', ['readAsDataURL', 'onload']);
    spyOn(window as any, 'FileReader').and.returnValue(mockReader);
    spyOn(component, 'getUploadFormGroup').and.returnValue(mockFormGroup);
    spyOn(component, 'getLoadCallback').and.callThrough();

    component.onUploadFile(mockEvt as any, mockIndex, mockIsReq);

    expect((window as any).FileReader).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mockReader.readAsDataURL).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockFile);
    expect(component.getUploadFormGroup).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockIndex, mockIsReq);
    expect(component.getLoadCallback).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockFormGroup, mockFile, mockReader);
  });
```

Of course you can change mock values and create more unit tests...

Comment: I've created a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-template-9unota?file=app%2Fhello.component.spec.ts) as well.

Comment: Terrific answer!  Thank you for the detail!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today as well, and I found this simple solution that works

```html
<input type="file" multiple (change)="onFileSelect($event)">
```

```ts
it('should call onFileSelect() when files manually selected with the file input', () => {
  spyOn(component, 'onFileSelect').and.callThrough();
  fixture.detectChanges();

  const file = new File(['this is file content!'], 'dummy.txt');
  const dt = new DataTransfer();
  dt.items.add(file);
  dt.items.add(file);

  const inputElDebug = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[type="file"]'));
  const inputEl: HTMLInputElement = inputElDebug.nativeElement;
  inputEl.files = dt.files;

  const changeEvent = new Event('change');
  inputEl.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);

  fixture.detectChanges();

  expect(component.onFileSelect).toHaveBeenCalled();
  //or
  //expect(component.onFileSelect).toHaveBeenCalledWith(changeEvent);
});
```

And of course you can leave out the actual files if you don't need to do anything with them, but if you do they are easily made available