# jasmine spyon readAsBinaryString method of FileReader property

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a function that uses a FileReader. I would like to spy on the *readAsBinaryString* method.

In my component I have the following property   `reader: FileReader;`
In addition, inside the insert method, I have the following statement:

```
this.reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

Here is the code inside of my spec file:

```
  fit('', () => {
    const e: any = {
        ...
      }
    };
    const readerSpy = spyOn(catalog.reader, 'readAsBinaryString');
    catalog.insert(e);
    expect(readerSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

I get the following error:

> Error:  : could not find an object to spy upon for
>   readAsBinaryString()

Comment: could you provide your component class code (at least `insert` method)?

Comment: @sherlock.92 the code inside insert is irrelevant. I mentioned in my post that I have a call to readAsBinaryString and I would like to spy on it from the spec file.

Comment: Got it. Check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock global `FileReader` like this:

```
    const mockReader: FileReader = jasmine.createSpyObj('FileReader', ['readAsBinaryString']);
    spyOn(window as any, 'FileReader').and.returnValue(mockReader);
```

And then in your unit test this should work as expected:

```
  it('test', () => {
    ...
    catalog.insert(someMockData);
    expect(catalog.reader.readAsBinaryString).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Check this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-template-nxaws3?file=app/hello.component.spec.ts)

**Edit**

If you call `new FileReader()` in the insert method (at the start), so you can mock `FileReader` inside the `it` (or inside `beforeEach` method, if you have multiple similar unit tests):

```
  it('test', () => {
    const mockReader: FileReader = jasmine.createSpyObj('FileReader', ['readAsBinaryString']);
    spyOn(window as any, 'FileReader').and.returnValue(mockReader);
    // other mocks

    catalog.insert(someMockData);

    expect(catalog.reader.readAsBinaryString).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // other expects
  });
```

Comment: So there is no way to spy on a FileReader property in a component? I have to mock a global FileReader instead?

Comment: How and where are you calling `new FileReader()`  ?

Comment: I didn't see your demo, but now I think I understand this. I am calling new FileReader() in the insert method (at the start). I should have made it more clear in my post. I will try the solution.

Comment: Cool. I've also answered the similar question, so you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51970681/angular-jasmine-unit-test-change-event-for-inputtype-file/51975819#51975819) as well