# How to mock "<input type="file"" in Angular 6 unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, code-coverage, angular-cli-v6

I need to write a unit test case for below control which accept only json file. I need to set mock as json file to increase my code coverage report.

```html
<input
  #fileInput
  hidden
  id="importFile"
  type="file"
  accept=".json"
  (change)="importKeys($event)"
  >
```

Comment: Have you looked at this SO question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51970681/angular-jasmine-unit-test-change-event-for-inputtype-file/51975819

Comment: awesome. it suits me. Thanks.